# Reserved keyword in Oracle database trigger?

Tags: sql, oracle, oracle11g

When I try to create a trigger in Oracle 11g, I get the following errors:

> ORA-06552: PL/SQL: COMPILATION UNIT ANALYSIS TERMINATED
>
> ORA-06553: PLS-320: THE DECLARATION OF THIS TYPE OF THIS EXPRESSION IS INCOMPLETE OR MALFORMED.

I've tried changing the table name from EVENT to another table and the trigger compiles but my search for reserved keywords only indicates EVENTS though.  Is something else wrong with the trigger?

```
CREATE TRIGGER GEN_EVENT_ID
  BEFORE INSERT ON EVENT
  FOR EACH ROW
BEGIN
  :NEW.ID := EVENT_ID_SEQ.NEXTVAL;
END;
```

Table

```
CREATE TABLE EVENT (
    ID NUMBER(19,0) NOT NULL,
    TIMESTAMP TIMESTAMP NOT NULL,
    NAME VARCHAR2(255)
);
```

Comment: There must be something you are not telling us, because that certainly works: http://sqlfiddle.com/#!4/7b121/1 Btw: are you aware that there is nothing "magic" about the number 255? It's just as good as 200 or 321 - no optimization whatsoever will take place because you chose 255 over e.g. 300

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`Id` appears in the `v$RESERVED_WORDS` view, which is the view of SQL keywords. Check this [link](http://docs.oracle.com/cd/B19306_01/server.102/b14237/dynviews_2048.htm) for more information on this.

```
Select *
  From V$RESERVED_WORDS
 Where KEYWORD = 'ID'
```

While `Id` is not marked as `Reserved` in this view, there seems to be some problem with using column names that appear in that list for `triggers` as stated in this other [SO question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/284653/oracle-why-does-creating-trigger-fail-when-there-is-a-field-called-timestamp).

If you read it you will see the OP had the same problem but with `timestamp`. In the other SO question a workaround was suggested that worked for the OP. If you change the column name the problem should disappear.

---

**Update**

Seeing your table declaration, all of your column names appear in the `V$RESERVED_WORDS`. Particularly the `timestamp` column is the same one mentioned in the other SO question (see link above) as being problematic for triggers.

My suggestion is to rename both the table and its columns. For example:

```
Create Table my_EVENT (
    event_Id Number(19,0) Not Null,
    event_Timestamp Timestamp Not Null,
    event_Name Varchar2(255)
);
```

Comment: I changed the column name to EVENT_ID and it still doesn't resolve the error.  The same error message still comes up with an additional `06552.00000 - "PL/SQL: %s" *Cause: *Action: Vendor code 6552 Error at Line:2 Column:17`.  Line 2, column 17 is the table name.

Comment: Is your table still named as `EVENT` or `EVENTS`? If yes, can you try renaming it as well? It might well be that by renaming the column a before hidden error has arisen.

Comment: Tried both `EVENT` and `EVENTS` with column name `EVENT_ID`.  Same error occurs.

Comment: Sorry, I meant to change the table name to something different than `EVENT` or `EVENTS`.

Comment: If that did not help then maybe the problem lies in the table. Can you please edit the question to add your table creation script? Also, if you are using `SQL*Plus` try `show errors` to check for syntax errors.

Comment: I've updated the question with the creation statement.  I'm not familiar with `SQL*Plus`, using `Oracle SQL Developer`.

Comment: I updated the answer after seeing your table script. Hope that helps.

Comment: Thanks.  `TIMESTAMP` was the issue in this case.